# PHP: Array with foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a and Array which looks like this:

```
$sms = array(
  'from' => 'DummyFrom', 
  'to' => '+46709751949',
  'message' => 'Hello hello!'
);
echo sendSMS ($sms) . "\n";
```

what i'm trying to do is to put this array within a foreach loop so it can be executed multiple time (based on the given times from mysql database). to explain it better, I did something like this:

```
if (is_array($g_numbers)) {
    foreach ($g_numbers as $number) {
        $sms = array(
            'from' => 'DummyFrom',
            'to' => "" . $number . "",
            'message' => 'Hello hello!'
        );
        echo sendSMS($sms) . "\n";
    }
}
```

but that is wrong and its stops the PHP page to execute properly without any errors!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

**My full code :**

```
<?php
$people       = array();
$sql          = "SELECT id, g_name, numbers FROM groups WHERE g_name='$groups'";
$query        = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $g_id               = $row['id'];
    $g_name             = $row['g_name'];
    $g_numbers          = $row['numbers'];
    $people[$g_numbers] = $g_numbers;

}
?>
<?
// Example to send SMS using the 46elks service
// Change $username, $password and the mobile number to send to

function sendSMS($sms)
{

    // Set your 46elks API username and API password here
    // You can find them at https://dashboard.46elks.com/
    $username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password) . "\r\n" . "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => http_build_query($sms),
            'timeout' => 10
        )
    ));

    $response = file_get_contents('https://api.46elks.com/a1/SMS', false, $context);

    if (!strstr($http_response_header[0], "200 OK"))
        return $http_response_header[0];

    return $response;
}
if (is_array($g_numbers)) {
    foreach ($g_numbers as $number) {
        $sms = array(
            'from' => 'DummyFrom',
            /* Can be up to 11 alphanumeric characters */
            'to' => "" . $number . "",
            /* The mobile number you want to send to */
            'message' => 'Hello hello!'
        );
        echo sendSMS($sms) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are foreaching `$g_numbers` and not providing us that code. is `$g_numbers` an array when you `print_r` it? Is it even populated? Is it an empty array? What is the output to `print_r($g_numbers);`

Comment: @Jesse, i've added my entire code now. sorry about that.

Comment: `$g_numbers = $row['numbers'];` are you sure you don't want to do `$g_numbers[] = $row['numbers'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work because tables values are stored in $people:

```
if (is_array($people)) {
  foreach ($people as $number) {
    $sms = array(
        'from' => 'DummyFrom',
        /* Can be up to 11 alphanumeric characters */
        'to' => "" . $number . "",
        /* The mobile number you want to send to */
        'message' => 'Hello hello!'
    );
    echo sendSMS($sms) . "\n";
  }
}
```